# Show jQuery Popup only once and only on starting page

Tags: jquery, cookies, set, hide, show

I've been asked to expand a given code, making it so that the box generated only shows once per visit.
After reading up on it, the problem didn't seem too complicated, but for some reason the code just doesn't work- now the layer isn't shown at all.
Since I'm not too familiar with jQuery and the original author isn't available, I was hoping someone might give me a push in the right direction?
For testing purposes, I tried to set the cookie to expire in 2 hours.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
/* Popup on starting page */
<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/" || $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/index.php") :
?>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    if ($.cookie('test') !='1'){

jQuery("body").append("<div class=\"vbox-shadow\"></div>");
jQuery(".vbox-shadow").fadeIn(function() { 
jQuery("body").append("<div class=\"vbox-layer\"></div>");
jQuery(".vbox-layer").html("<span class=\"vbox-close\">X</span><a href=\"/link/target.html\"><img src=\"/images/popup_image.jpg\" /><br /></a>");
jQuery(".vbox-close").click(function(e) {
jQuery(".vbox-layer").hide(function()  {
jQuery(".vbox-layer").remove();
jQuery(".vbox-close").remove();
jQuery(".vbox-shadow").fadeOut(function() { jQuery(".vbox-shadow").remove(); });
});
});
jQuery(".vbox-shadow").click(function(e) {
jQuery(".vbox-layer").hide(function()  {
jQuery(".vbox-layer").remove();
jQuery(".vbox-close").remove();
jQuery(".vbox-shadow").fadeOut(function() { jQuery(".vbox-shadow").remove(); });
});
});
$.cookie('test', '1', { expires:7200000});
});}
});
<?php
endif;
?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookie might have expired as well. so in that case $.cookie('test') will return undefined, try changing your $.cookie('test') !='1' to if (!$.cookie('test')){

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @artm!
Doesn't seem to change anything, though - as soon as I add the lines to check/set the cookie, the layer doesn't show at all.
In addition, Webmaster Toolkit doesn't show the "test"-cookie to ever have been set in the first place.

Comment: Something doesn't seem right, the <a href="https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#expires">documentation</a> for jquery.cookie states that the expiration is a number in DAYS.

And, for sanity's sake, you may want to set the cookie's path to the root folder, like this:

`$.cookie('test','1',{path:'/',expires:7200000});`

Comment: put a breakpoint in jQuery( document ).ready(function() { and check what $.cookie('test') returns.

Comment: Sorry for the bad link... <https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#expires> states that the expiry number is reflected in days, so 7200000 may be invalid.

Comment: 7200000 may be invalid but I don't think setting the path will make a difference, no path equals "/" anyway

Comment: Set the path and changed the expire to 365 - so far no luck. Will try the breakpoint next.

Comment: Try the break point, you want to show the popup when the cookie doesn't exist, not when it's not 1. For testing purposes set the expiry to something small first. And you might want to change your condition so if the cookie exists then show the popup and change the cookies date to +100 years, so you don't show the cookie again if it's been shown once.

Comment: No luck.... it seems as if the cookie is never even set in the first place.
I managed to get a PHP-cookie in place, though, which seems to do the trick just as well.
Thank you very much for your help, DevlshOne and artm!

Comment: Are you setting the cookie after you show the popup?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work using a PHP-generated cookie as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
/* Popup on starting page */
<?php
if(($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/" || $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/index.php")&&($_COOKIE['NoPopup']!='true')) :
?>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

jQuery("body").append("<div class=\"vbox-shadow\"></div>");
jQuery(".vbox-shadow").fadeIn(function() { 
jQuery("body").append("<div class=\"vbox-layer\"></div>");
jQuery(".vbox-layer").html("<span class=\"vbox-close\">X</span><a href=\"/link/to/page.html\"><img src=\"/images/popup.jpg\" /><br /></a>");
jQuery(".vbox-close").click(function(e) {
jQuery(".vbox-layer").hide(function()  {
jQuery(".vbox-layer").remove();
jQuery(".vbox-close").remove();
jQuery(".vbox-shadow").fadeOut(function() { jQuery(".vbox-shadow").remove(); });
});
});
jQuery(".vbox-shadow").click(function(e) {
jQuery(".vbox-layer").hide(function()  {
jQuery(".vbox-layer").remove();
jQuery(".vbox-close").remove();
jQuery(".vbox-shadow").fadeOut(function() { jQuery(".vbox-shadow").remove(); });
});
});
});
});

<?php
endif;
$value='true';
setcookie("NoPopup", $value, time()+60*60*6);
?>
</script>
```